# Getting the title from specific custom post type that is set using ACF and reusing it

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Basically, I have page that displays custom post type using Advanced custom fields plugin. [Here you can see how it looks at the moment](http://ladappb.grandem.lv/izglitiba/). Each post is displayed as table row with several fields that are set using Advanced custom fields.
Each post will have button "Pieteikties" which is used to open up contact form and apply to given post (each post is course with ability to sign up using pop up contact form). **So my question is how can I show individual title for each course in contact form?** For example when I click on "Pieteikties" for course with name "Otrais kurss" the pop up contact for would show "Pieteikšanās forma kursam Otrais kurss" and when I click on "Hematoloģija" the form would show "Pieteikšanās forma kursam Hematoloģija".

This is the way custom posts are displayed.

```
        <tr>
        <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
        <td><?php the_field('lektors'); ?></td>
        <td><?php the_field('datums');?><br><?php the_field('laiks');?></td>
        <td><?php the_field('norises_vieta');?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php the_field('cena');?><br><span class="sub-info"><?php the_field('apmaksas_veids');?></span></td>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup-step1" class="red-border">Pieteikties »</a><br><span class="sub-info"><?php the_field('pieteiksanas_beigu_datums');?></span>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Most likely you'd want to write some jQuery. I'd suggest writing a click event on the button that finds the course name, and then replace the text at the top of the form with that same text. I'd suggest adding a class to the <td> that houses the course name for easier access.

Comment: Haven't thought of that, thanks, works very well!